# algorithm2e: do N times

Tags: pseudocode

I want to write this in algorithm2e pseudocode:

```
Do N times
   stuff that has to be done N times
end
```

or maybe

```
Repeat N times
   stuff that has to be done N times
end
```

Since the loop body does not depend on a loop index, introducing one (like in a typical "for" loop) seems overkill.

My current best solution is

```
\For{$N$ times}{
  do stuff
}
```

but the output, "**for** *N times* **do**" is unclear.

(there are Do and Repeat commands in algorithm2e, but they both use end conditions: `Do...while` and `Repeat...until`, so not what I'm looking for.)

Comment: According to the docs there's `\Repeat`, so you should have a look at the package's documentation.

Comment: There is indeed Repeat, but that gives "repeat ... until condition"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems there is no such built-in loop. Luckily, you can create your own! In algoritm2e, there are loops "with the condition at the start", or "with the condition at the end". To create your own "at the start" loop, do:

```
\SetKwFor{RepTimes}{repeat}{times}{end}
```

Then, to use it:

```
\RepTimes{100}{
    foobar
}
```

[image: rendered latex image]