# How to write a "repeat n times" loop in algorithmic?

Tags: algorithmic, pseudocode

In `algorithmic`, I would like to write a loop that will look like the following:

```
   repeat $n$ times:
      [command]
   end
```

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434664/algorithm2e-do-n-times), explaining how to do this in algorithms2e, but it does not work with algorithmic.

EDIT: This is what I do now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \WHILE{Repeated at most $T$ times}
    \STATE Do Stuff
    \ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a full MWE (showing an algorithm with a normal loop for example that you want to change into a repeat n loop), expecially for pseudocode questions it is important to be very clear about the setup.

Comment: @Marijn added example

Comment: We need something that can be compiled on https://texlive.net/run . ;-)

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi as projetmbc mentioned, this code is not compilable. Please add the documentclass and packages, begin/end document, and anything else needed to actually compile the code. Then we can be sure that we have the exact same setup as you, which guarantees that a solution also works for you. Moreover, it saves time for people trying to answer if they don't have to add boilerplate code themselves.

Comment: @Marijn edited, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new block using `algpseudocode`: `\RepeatN`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\algdef{SE}[REPEATN]{RepeatN}{End}[1]{\algorithmicrepeat\ #1 \textbf{times}}{\algorithmicend}

\begin{algorithmic}
    \RepeatN{$n$}
    \State Do stuff
    \End
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

For backwards compatibility with `algorithmic` you can use `algcompatible`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\algdef{SE}[REPEATN]{REPEATN}{END}[1]{\algorithmicrepeat\ #1 \textbf{times}}{\algorithmicend}

\begin{algorithmic}
    \REPEATN{$n$}
    \STATE Do stuff
    \END
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution uses `algpseudocode`, but the project I work on uses `algorithmic`. 
When I add `\usepacakge{algpseudocode}` I get `\algorithmic already defined`. If I remove `algorithmic`, then some other parts of the code (e.g. \STATE) stop working.

Comment: `algpseudocode` is a layout for `algorithmicx` which is a more customizable replacement of `algorithmic`. The main difference is that only the first letter of the command is capitalized...

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi this illustrates the importance of a full compilable MWE, now you got an answer that you can't easily use because you didn't add your exact setup to your question at first.

Comment: @Marijn You are right. I did not know that there are two versions of algorithmic in two different packages.

Comment: I added a version that is backwards compatible to `algorithmic`

Answer (score 3):

For comparison a version that uses only the internals of the `algorithmic` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\REPEATN}[1]{\ALC@it\algorithmicrepeat%
\ #1 \textbf{times}\begin{ALC@rpt}}%
\newcommand{\ENDREPEAT}{\end{ALC@rpt}\ALC@it\algorithmicend}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \WHILE{Repeated at most $T$ times}
    \STATE Do Stuff
    \ENDWHILE
    \REPEATN{$n$}
    \STATE Do Stuff
    \ENDREPEAT
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that the solution of DG' with `algcompatible` is easier to use.